# uploading .csv to database

Tags: php, oracle

I want to upload a csv file to be inserted into the oracle database. I have this data

```
SMS-MH-CL52,MILLHOUSE,1,COLUMN,H-300X150X6.5X9,8.1,254
SMS-MH-CL53,MILLHOUSE,1,COLUMN,H-300X150X6.5X9,8.1,254
SMS-MH-CL54,MILLHOUSE,1,COLUMN,H-300X150X6.5X9,8.1,254
```

and I keep getting this error,

```
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("WELTESADMIN"."MASTER_DRAWING"."HEAD_MARK") in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\Content\Uploader\read_data.php on line 90

Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("WELTESADMIN"."MASTER_DRAWING"."HEAD_MARK") in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\Content\Uploader\read_data.php on line 90
```

and my php code is like this

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
set_time_limit(0);

//Move selected file to the temporary folder
if($_FILES['file']['name'] != ""){
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "".$_FILES["file"]["name"])
        or die ("COULD NOT COPY FILE");
}else{
die("No File Specified");
}

        echo ' Filename : '.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        echo ' Filesize : '.$_FILES['file']['size'];
        echo ' Filetype : '.$_FILES['file']['type'];


// NOW OPEN THE FILE
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");

// AND READ THE FILE
$content = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

$subject = $content;

// AND NOW THE BEST PART IS THE REGEX MANIPULATION
$search = '/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\,
        ([a-zA-Z]+)\,
        ([0-9]+)\,
        ([a-zA-Z\s\-\_]+)\,
        ([a-zA-Z0-9\[\*\-\.]+)\,
        ([0-9\.]+)\,
        ([0-9\.]+)/';

// MATCHING TO THE TABLE
preg_match_all($search, $subject, $match);
$isi = file($filename);

// COUNT THE ARRAY ELEMENTS
$numRow = sizeof($isi);

for($i=0;$i<$numRow;$i++){
$headmark = isset($match[1])?($match[1]) : '';
$project = isset($match[2])?($match[2]) : '';
$quantity = isset($match[3])?($match[3]) : '';
$comptype = isset($match[4])?($match[4]) : '';
$profile = isset($match[5])?($match[5]) : '';
$surface = isset($match[6])?($match[6]) : '';
$weight = isset($match[7])?($match[7]) : '';


$sql = "INSERT INTO MASTER_DRAWING (REV_NO, REV_DATE, HEAD_MARK, COMP_TYPE, QTY, WEIGHT, SURFACE, PROFILE, PROJECT_NAME)
        VALUES ('1', SYSDATE, :headmark, :comptype, :quantity, :weight, :surface, :profile, :project)";

$importParse = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

oci_bind_by_name($importParse, ":headmark", $headmark[$i]);
oci_bind_by_name($importParse, ":comptype", $comptype[$i]);
oci_bind_by_name($importParse, ":quantity", $quantity[$i]);
oci_bind_by_name($importParse, ":weight", $weight[$i]);
oci_bind_by_name($importParse, ":surface", $surface[$i]);
oci_bind_by_name($importParse, ":profile", $profile[$i]);
oci_bind_by_name($importParse, ":project", $project[$i]);

$importRes = oci_execute($importParse);

if ($importRes){
    oci_commit($conn);
} else {
    oci_rollback($conn);
}
```

Please help me. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're trying to insert NULL into WELTESADMIN.MASTER_DRAWING.HEAD_MARK, which -apparently- isn't nullable.

Comment: @GolezTrol I know that the data is null. I don't know where did I made the mistake that the data becomes null. The regex seems to be fine as I tested it in the regextester.com

Answer (score 0):

You assign the matches to `$headmark`, which becomes a normal string variable *). On each iteration you overwrite this value with the next.

Then, you read `$headmark[$i]` to store it in the database, but that doesn't make sense. I think that line should just read

```
oci_bind_by_name($importParse, ":headmark", $headmark /* Without [$i] */);
```

This goes for the other variables as well, of course.

-edit-

*) Looking again at your code, $headmark might be an array, because `preg_match_all` might return a multi dimensional array in $match. But if that's the case, then the array index you need will be always the same, so it could be `$headmark[0]` or `$headmark[1]`, but not `$headmark[$i]`, since $i is the line number, and is therefor unrelated to the interpretation of the line itself.

Comment: when I do as you followed, these errors came up,

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\Content\Uploader\read_data.php on line 81

Comment: Have you tried viewing what is in `$headmark` and what is in `$headmark[$i]`? Also checked what type they are? They might be an array, but then the index `[$i]` is probably wrong. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Have you checked the result of `preg_match_all`? Have you checked what is in $heading? You can try to debug the inserting part, but it's better to take a step back and see where it went wrong. So rather than just copying any suggestion, check what is the actual value you get, and also check the return values for functions like `preg_match`, because that will also tell you whether a certain step went wrong.